# Determinant of a bilinear map

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Given arbitrary vector space $V$ over the field $K$ (dim$V=d<\infty$), the space of endomorphisms is isomorphic to (1,1)-tensor space over $V$:
$$End(V) \cong T^1_1V$$
Let $\phi$ be some endomorphism:  $ \phi:V\to V$
Then for any non-vanishing volume-form $\omega$, and for any basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_d\}$ on $V$ we define the determinant of endomorphism $\phi$ as:
$$det(\phi)=\frac{\omega(\phi(e_1),\dots,\phi(e_d))}{\omega(e_1\dots,e_d)} \in K$$
(Where division can be thought as a multplication of inverse on K)
Thus, in this way we can define determinants of (1,1)-tensors.
Question: Is there any similar well-defined notion of determinant for (0,2)-tensors/blinear maps $$T^0_2V = \{ T:V\times V \to K\}$$ that does not rely on matrix representaions?  Can it be defined it terms of endomorphisms (purely as maps)?

Comment: The usual characterization of the determinant through exterior algebra should work for any rank two tensor, no? A bilinear form is just a linear map $V \to V^*$, which induces a map $\Lambda^d V \to \Lambda^d V^*$. As these are both 1-dimensional spaces, this map is multiplication by a scalar, the determinant.

Comment: @AlexProvost No. That does define the determinant, but the determinant is a member of $\Lambda^dV^*\otimes\Lambda^dV^*$, not a scalar.

Comment: @OscarCunningham The induced map $\Lambda^d V \to \Lambda^d V^*$ itself may be considered as an element of your tensor space, yes, but that's not my point.

Comment: @AlexProvost Right, I read the part of the question where it says "does not rely on matrix representations" as meaning that we should avoid a basis.

Comment: @OscarCunningham But the resulting scalar is independent of any choice of basis.

Comment: @AlexProvost No, I think that's false. If you double the length of one of your basis vectors then your scalar will multiply by four.

Comment: @OscarCunningham I think you may be right; I can't think straight right now.

Comment: @OscarCunningham So if it's just some element of $\Lambda^d V^* \otimes \Lambda^d V^*$ is there any way to define it explicitly? Like for a given $\phi \in T^0_2 V$, $det(\phi) := ?$

Comment: @SergeyDylda I don't have a good way to do it. I'd just pick a basis and find the matrix representation.

Comment: @OscarCunningham But can we think of determinant as: $det(\phi) := \Lambda^{dimV}\phi$ such that $\Lambda^{dimV}\phi (e_1\land \dots \land e_{dimV}) = \phi(e_1) \land \dots \land \phi(e_{dimV}) $ for $\phi: V \to V^*$ ?

Comment: @OscarCunningham I believe what I had in mind was that the scalar so obtained is independent of the choice of basis *if* the target space is endowed with the dual basis. (Just like how the scalar obtained from a map $V \to V$ between 1-dimensional spaces is independent of the chosen basis of $V$ as long as we pick the same basis for the domain and the codomain.) So in this case, any choice of basis $e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_d$ for $\Lambda^d V$ induces a basis $e_1^* \wedge \cdots \wedge e_d^*$ for $\Lambda^d V^*$, and with respect to these bases we get a scalar independent of the $(e_i)$.

Comment: What properties do you want your "determinant" to have?  It is easy to see that if every element of $K$ has a square root, then if $V$ has dimension one all nontrivial bilinear maps $V\times V\to K$ are related by a change of basis.  So if you want your "determinant" to be basis-invariant, it would have to be the same for all nontrivial bilinear maps on a one-dimensional space.

Comment: @AlexProvost: No, that doesn't work: the determinant still changes if you change the basis.  Think about the case where $V$ is 1-dimensional and $\phi$ maps $e_1$ to $e_1^*$, so it has determinant $1$ for the basis $\{e_1\}$.  If you replace $e_1$ by $2e_1$, then the dual basis vector gets halved.  But $\phi$ maps $2e_1$ to $2e_1^*=4(e_1^*/2)$, so in the new basis $\{2e_1\}$, $\phi$ has determinant $4$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks! I see it now. Somehow I totally overlooked that the dual basis vectors transform transform inversely to the original basis vectors. (Duh!)

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, I see. So in general case for arbitrary bilinear map our deterimnant does change under the change of basis. Then a question:  change of basis can be represented by endomorphisms $A: V \to V$ and $B: V \to V$ such that $A = B^{-1}$. How can define our determinant to actually see that it is dependent on those endomorphisms?

Comment: @SergeyDylda Yeah, that definition works. I just didn't know if you were happy with $\Lambda$ or wanted something more concrete.